# The range reference in the formula changes in one case but doesn't in other

Tags: google-sheets, reference, google-sheets-formula, range

The `3` in `A3:A` or `B$3:B` doesn't change when we move the 3rd row to any other row, but it changes when we move any other row to 3rd row position, or when insert a new row (Insert below in 2nd row or insert above in 4th row)?
Also the reference A3 doesn't change in any case.
(By move I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CatE.png))

Example: [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11pnTwCnUXgryBpxP3j7fx1LP0Pk_eJfsEiLMLjr7GRw/edit?usp=sharing)  (Feel free to play with)

[image]

If I move the 3rd row to any other row position, the formula remains the same
**For Eg:**  I moved 3rd row to 4th row position, I get this:

[image]

The formula remained the same,
But now if I instead move say any row to 3rd row,
**For Eg:** If I move 4th row to 3rd row position like this:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

The formula changes, Similary if I say move 2 more rows to 4th row or even 3rd position then the range from A4:A & B$4:B would become A6:A & B$6:B. If you notice A3 remains the same in all cases irrespectively.

I know I can keep the range constant by using: `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN(A3),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROWS(A:A),COLUMN(A3),4))`  but that's not my question is, my question is:

**Why is the range not changing in first case but changing in second case what exactlty is happening? and even if it's why is the cell reference A3 not changing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts is that the ranges are considered from "up to down". Between the division the upper division of cells. Between the "upper border" of row 3 and the "lower border" of the last row. I experimented with the range A3:A7, B$3:B$7, and the same happens if any row inside the range is moved below the lower border of the prior 7th row, shirinkig to row 6:

[image]

So when you're dragging or creating anything outside the limits, it's considered out of range. See it illustrated with the borders in blue:

[image]

I'm just moving the rows, I haven't re-drawn any border:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### SUGGESTION

After playing around on your test sheet with the provided conditions, here are my thoughts on the behavior shown in your formulas:

1. First, regarding moving a row down: this shouldn't really affect the overall range of the 1st two formulas, since they are being moved within the overall range (A3:A and B$3:B). As for the value on cell C2, which references the value on cell A3, what it tracks is the cell reference itself and not the value contained on the cell it originally was referencing.

   For instance, moving down the 3rd row means C2 is now tracking cell A4, which basically is the same value. (see sample output below, displaying said behavior)

[image]

2. As for moving rows upward, usually this also doesn't affect the overall range **unless** the movement is within one row of the range. In your example, the formula is referencing the range A3:A, which starts at the 3rd row. Moving other rows upward shouldn't be an issue except for the 4th row, wherein by moving it up, it overrides the starting point of the range which as you've also seen it now shows as A4:A. This also applies to inserting a new row just above the range's starting point, since that new row is technically not included within the range, so what happened is the starting point just moved down.

   Normally, you can revert this by just swapping the two rows back; or, like what you have observed, continue moving the next adjacent rows upward to "shrink" the overall range.

In summary, the movement of the rows (or columns) affects the cell reference on your formulas, as it tracks the original cell referenced, and not the value contained on that cell. So it doesn't really matter if the values on cell A3 changes due to the movement, if the "original" A3 cell has moved up or down, then its reference follows along, which is what the formula keeps track of.